# android: onActivityResult() order of execution

Tags: android

I am a *newbie* to android app development.So I am having confusion with `onActivityResult()` method.

In `onCreate()` method I made a button `onClickListener` which on clicked will call `startActivityForResult` for selection of images from gallery.
What does exactly happen after onClickListener is called.Does my previous activity restarts again by calling `onCreate()` method or resumes by calling `onResume()` method.But what I have seen is that still onCreate() method is responding while clicking button and taking me to gallery.
What is the exact order of execution of this one with activity life cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, onRestart() -> onStart() -> onActivityResult() -> onResume() is what happens after choosing a picture from the gallery.
An activity only needs to call onCreate() and assign onClickListeners once per life cycle.

Comment: Let me give brief explanation of my code: In onCreate() method I added onClickListener and this takes me to gallery.Then after defining my own onActivityResult()  I'm not having any other except onCreate() method(like onResume() ).But Still I am able to click the button and go to gallery which one is defined in onCreate() method .Can I know where I am going wrong plz?

Comment: All the lifecycle events (onStart(), onResume(), etc)happen regardless whether you code them or not. By coding them, you are in fact overriding them. Also, onCreate isn't called every time a button is clicked...just it's onClickListener which exists separately from whatever lifecycle event you coded it in.

Comment: @manitejavarma Why do you think you are doing it wrong ? You original activity *is alive* during gallery is shown in front of it, and you simply get some callbacks (explained in this answer) when user makes selection and goes back to original activity.

Comment: I do have less reputation to mark up. Can you solve another problem?

Comment: As I said in my code in onActivityResult() method I started a thread which does not take much time.But when clicking button and selection picture the callback function is not starting the thread again .What could be the reason?

Comment: @kiruwka Thank you...and can I know solution for this?

Comment: Can you make a new question, and post the code from your onActivityResult() and where you startActivityForResult()?

Comment: I think it makes more sense as a separate question, but however you want to do it

Answer (score 1):

Overide all lifecycle methods (like onStart, onStop...) and add yours log if you want to know what happens with your Activity

something like that:

```
onStart(){
super.onStart();
Log.i("MyTag","onStart");
}
```

and look at LogCat with tag:MyTag :)
also look at this https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

The only difference from calling `startActivity` vs `startActivityForResult` is that when your first activity is resumed, you will get a callback to onActivityResult (in case the second activity called explicitly to `setResult()`).

Regarding the lifecycle, after going back from your second activity (by finishing the image selection or clicking back button), your first activity will be resumed and not created again. You can review Activities lifecycle in Android documentation [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: What if there is no `onResume` method in my activity?

Comment: If you are not using onResume to make any processing, there's no need to add it. None of the lifecycle callbacks are required to be implemented, but probably you will need to use them to handle some logic, onCreate for instance, you will need it to set the content view of your activity

Comment: Thank you! Got an idea about it.